# Regex to change old url to new with wordpress redirection

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirect

I want to redirect for example

```
www.mydomain.com/my-profile.html?userId=18681
```

to

```
www.mydomain.com/members
```

what shall i put in my Source URL?

I have more than 2000 404 errors on webmaster because i changed from cms to cms, so  i want to fix my redirection regex so not to enter the errors one bye one because I have

```
/my-profile.html?userId=18681
/my-profile.html?userId=12451
/my-profile.html?userId=9251
```

How can i make it general so it automatic redirects all to www.mydomain.com/members

I use this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Comment: [This regex](http://www.regexr.com/398q0) should match all of your urls with varying userId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're going about implementing the redirect. But from a purely regex standpoint, If I wanted to convert the top url format to the one you put below it, here is the find-and-replace format I would use:

s/(my-.+\d+)$/members/

So find 'my-', then one or more of any character, then ENDING with one or more digits. Replace that (starting with my- and ending with the digits) with 'members'.

Sorry if this does not solve your issue, and keep in mind this is 'perl compatible' format for regex, find-and-replace may (likely) be a formatted differently for the language you are implementing this with.

Comment: I use redirection plugin
I should enter the source URL which in this case: /my-profile.html?userId=18681 (this one which i have a problem in i want to make it generic like taking "my-profile.html?userId=anyNumberHere" and redirect it to /members)
and target URL which is in this case going to be: /members

Comment: then the above regex should find your my-profile.html?userId=anyNumberHere pattern: my-.+\d+$

Comment: I've put it and still not working 

source URL: my-.+\d+$ 
Target URL: /members

Comment: Try it without the end anchor maybe, I got better results with that. I usually like to be specific, and used end anchor as they all end with digits, but the following should work better: my-.+\d+